# Linear X Logarithmic scale

Tags: python, math

Given a line `X` pixels long like:

> ```
> 0-------|---V---|-------|-------|-------max
> ```

If `0 <= V <= max`, in linear scale `V` position would be `X/max*V` pixels.

How can I calculate the pixel position for a logarithmic scale, and starting from the pixel position how can I get back the value of V?

1. It is not homework
2. I want to know the math (no "use FOO-plotlib" comments, please)
3. I like Python

A logarithmic scale has the effect of "zooming" the left side of the scale. Is it possible to do the same thing for the right side instead?

[UPDATE]

Thanks for the math lessons!

I ended up not using logarithms. I've simply used the average value (in a set of values) as the center of the scale. This control is used to select group boundary percentiles for a set of values that will be used to draw a [choropleth chart](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Choropleth_map).

If the user chooses a symmetric scale (red mark=average, green mark=center, darkness represents the number of occurrences of a value):
[image]

An asymmetric scale makes fine-grained adjustments easier:
[image]

Comment: take log of all the values and the rest is the same.  be careful that you cannot have zero (log(0) is neg. inf) nor cross the sign

Comment: @yosukesabai: any hint about how to deal with very low values of `max`?

Comment: That's `(X/max)*V`, and nicer to read as `X * V/max`

Comment: How do you define zooming the right side?

Comment: @hamstergene: make the values on the right side of the scale more sparse in the chart.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

So you've got some arbitrary value `V`, and you know that 0 <= `V` <= `Vmax`. You want to calculate the x-coordinate of a pixel, call it `X`, where your "screen" has x-coordinates from 0 to `Xmax`. As you say, to do this the "normal" way, you'd do

```
X = Xmax * V / Vmax
V = Vmax * X / Xmax
```

I like to think of it like I'm first normalizing the value to lie between 0 and 1 by calculating `V / Vmax`, and then I multiply this value by the maximum to get a value between 0 and that maximum.

To do the same logaritmically you need a different lower limit for the `V` value. If V is ever <= 0, you get a `ValueError`. So let's say 0 < `Vmin` <= `V` <= `Vmax`. Then you need to find out *what* logarithm to use, as there are infinitely many of them. Three are commonly encountered, those with base 2, e and 10, which results in x-axis that look like this:

```
------|------|------|------|----      ------|------|------|------|----
    2^-1    2^0    2^1    2^2     ==       0.5     1      2      4

------|------|------|------|----      ------|------|------|------|----
    e^-1    e^0    e^1    e^2     ==       0.4     1     2.7    7.4

------|------|------|------|----      ------|------|------|------|----
    10^-1  10^0   10^1   10^2     ==       0.1     1     10     100
```

So in principle, if we can get at the exponents from the expressions to the left, we can use the same principle as above to get a value between 0 and `Xmax`, and this is of course where log comes in. Assuming you use base `b`, you can use these expressions to convert back and forth:

```
from math import log
logmax = log(Vmax / Vmin, b)
X = Xmax * log(V / Vmin, b) / logmax
V = Vmin * b ** (logmax * X / Xmax)
```

It's almost the same way of thinking, except you need to first make sure that `log(somevalue, b)` will give you a non-negative value. You do this by dividing by `Vmin` inside the `log` function. Now you may divide by the maximum value the expression can yield, which is of course `log(Vmax / Vmin, b)`, and you will get a value between 0 and 1, same as before.

The other way we need to first normalize (`X / Xmax`), then scale up again (`* logmax`) to the maximum expected by the inverse funciton. The inverse is to raise `b` to some value, by the way. Now if `X` is 0, `b ** (logmax * X / Xmax)` will equal 1, so to get the correct lower limit we multiply by `Vmin`. Or to put it another way, since the first thing we did going the other way was to divide by `Vmin`, we need to multiply with `Vmin` as the last thing we do now.

To "zoom" the "right side" of the equation, all you need to do is switch the equations, so you exponentiate going from `V` to `X` and take the logarithm going the other way. In principle, that is. Because you've also got to do something with the fact that `X` can be 0:

```
logmax = log(Xmax + 1, b)
X = b ** (logmax * (V - Vmin) / (Vmax - Vmin)) - 1
V = (Vmax - Vmin) * log(X + 1, b) / logmax + Vmin
```

Answer (score 3):

```
           Linear               Logarithmic
Forward    pos = V * X/max      pos = log(V) * X/log(max)
Reverse    V = pos * max/X      V = B^( pos * log(max)/X )
```

(B is logarithm's base)

Obviously you must ensure that V >= 1 (V=1 will correspond to pos=0, V=0..1 corresponds to -inf..0, and for V<0 logarithm is not defined).

Answer (score 2):

This can be easily extended for other functions. My measure of space is given in chars instead of pixels (thats why max==chars(or pixels)).
Only for positive values.

```
import math

def scale(myval, mode='lin'):
    steps = 7
    chars = max = 10 * steps

    if mode=='log':
        val = 10 * math.log10(myval)
    else:
        val = myval

    coord = []
    count = 0
    not_yet = True
    for i in range(steps):
        for j in range(10):
            count += 1
            if val <= count and not_yet:
                coord.append('V')
                not_yet = False
                pos = count
            elif j==9:
                coord.append('|')
            else:
                coord.append('*')

    graph = ''.join(coord)
    text = 'graph %s\n\n%s\nvalue = %5.1f   rel.pos. = %5.2f\n'
    print  text % (mode, graph, myval, chars * pos/max) 


scale(50, 'lin')
scale(50, 'log')
```

[image]

Hope the above is not considered FOO-plotlib. But damn it ! this is SO ! :-)